# How to view extremely large images?

Tags: png, file-size, jpg, windows

## Does anyone have a recommendation to view extremely large image files in Windows?

Default Windows image viewer tends to have issues with extremely large images. I'm talking about both large file size and large dimension images.

I've tried [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) but I don't like it.

---

Examples of problems with Windows Photo Viewer include crashes, random artifacts, incorrect rendering of transparencies. etc.. Just to name a few. There's more I can't think of right now.

Comment: Picasa photo viewer

Comment: Can you give more info on the problem with Windows Photo Viewer?

Comment: An extremely large monitor should help... Much as I hate Windows Photo Viewer, what problems does it have with "large" images? How large is "large"?

Comment: Have you tried [XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnview/) - I have no affiliation to this site/company.  Also what precisely are the problems with Windows image viewer, and what's wrong with IrfanView?

Comment: @WELZ Sure, For instance it can crash or cause random artifacts. Incorrect rendering of transparencies. etc.. Just to name a few

Comment: @usr2564301 Have you ever designed something high res that had to be to scale for a multi story building? That large approximately.

Comment: @usr2564301 I have a 4k monitor. It's not the issue.

Comment: Big scale arworks tend not be much larger from the monitors standpoint than high resolution art prints. Since once you go bigger your amount of pixels per area decrease as the vuman eye is only really sensitive to pixels per angle of view. Question is rather how many pixels your image is.

Comment: @joojaa I'm more concerned with the other problems I mentioned in my question with the default windows image viewer.

Comment: It is rather impossible to give you any advice without knowing how many pixels is big. 5000x5000 or 200000x200000 big as a house is devoid of any information.

Comment: @joojaa How about approximately 20,000x20,000 if you wanted an actual number. Maybe larger

Comment: You *might* try some more professional level image editing software. Most operating system applications are designed for the average user and often lack support for more "out of the norm" situations.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning IrfanView, I actually quite like it XD. Question answered for me.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can right the photo, click "open with" and select Google Chrome or any Browser you use. I have the same issues viewing with PDF files  that has large file size, but whenever I open it through Chrome, it views and works just right.

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome could not open my 98177x49247 PNG file, and neither could Firefox.  The Windows "Photos" app managed to open it, but only showed a low-resolution image.